# How do I rotate text string?

Tags: codenameone

How do I rotate a string to 90 degrees? The code doesn't work.

```
    Transform transform = g.getTransform();
    g.rotateRadians(1.571f);  //90 degree
    x = getX();
    y = getY();
    g.drawString("Title",x,y);
    g.setTransform(transform);
```

Show nothing(empty)

[image]

Remove g.rotateRadians(1.571f);  //90 degree

[image]

What I want

[image]

Comment: If variable transform is stored prior to rotate call and later restored on last line, are you not undoing your rotate?

Comment: Can you clarify what doesn't work?
I suggest calling `drawString` and not `drawChar` as the complexities of glyph shaping are far greater. This would also break for languages like Korean, Arabic and is far less efficient. I'm assuming nothing is showing because the coordinate system is rotated and the position is now outside of the screen. You need to make sure the new coordinates are within the new boundaries of the screen. I suggest using a fill rect call to debug this and get a sense of where everything is drawn.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the code and the screenshots it seems that you're rotating the text outside of the screen bounds as you're rotating from the top left corner to the left of the screen.

Another problem is clipping boundary, even if you solved the rotation problem through translation this isn't so simple. A component is clipped so you wouldn't be able to accidentally draw outside of its bounds.

What you need to do is create a component that would be tall enough on the right hand side of the screen (e.g. border layout `EAST`) and then rotate and translate that.

Since the coordinate points at the top left position, that would change when drawing vertically. You would need the pivot point of the rotation to revolve around the right area of the component not the left area where the text would normally start.

See:

```
Form hi = new Form("", new BorderLayout());
Label title = new Label("Title") {
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        int x = getX() + getPreferredH() - getUnselectedStyle().getHorizontalPadding();
        g.translate(x, getY());
        g.rotateRadians(1.571f);
        g.setColor(getUnselectedStyle().getFgColor());
        g.setFont(getUnselectedStyle().getFont());
        g.drawString(getText(), 0, 0);
        g.rotateRadians(-1.571f);
        g.translate(-x, -getY());
    }
};
hi.add(BorderLayout.EAST, title);
hi.show();
```

Which produces:

[image: Screenshot of code running]

Comment: Thank you. It doesn't seem very easy. That's not what I thought in the beginning.